# Python list.sort() not working as expected

Tags: python

The compare function passed to the sort function seems to working correctly, but the final array is not sorted properly.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def cmp(t1, t2):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    print(t1)
    print(t2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    if t1[0] < t2[0]:
        print("Returning True")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        return True
    if t1[0] == t2[0]:
        print(t1[1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        print(t2[1])
        print("Returning: " + str(t1[1] > t2[1]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        return t1[1] > t2[1]
    print("Returning False")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    return False

a = [(1, 'coding'), (2, 'i'), (2, 'love')]
a.sort(key=cmp_to_key(cmp))
print(a)
```

generates the following output:

```
(2, 'i')
(1, 'coding')
Returning False
(2, 'love')
(2, 'i')
love
i
Returning: True
[(1, 'coding'), (2, 'i'), (2, 'love')]
```

So, when (2, 'love') is compared against (2, 'i'), the compare function returns True, meaning that (2, 'love') should come before (2, 'i'). But that's not what happens in the final array. Any clues?

Thank you!

Comment: is this python2.7? Also what's the expected output

Comment: A comparator function isn't supposed to return True/False, it's supposed to return positive/zero/negative based on how the two items compare to each other.

Comment: Thank you, @jasonharper ! I din't know that was the case in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your approach is explained in the comments, so I will just add that this can be achieved in a much shorter fashion:

```
a = [(1, 'coding'), (2, 'i'), (2, 'love')]
a.sort(key=lambda t: (-t[0], t[1]), reverse=True)
# same as a.sort(key=lambda t: (t[0], -t[1])) but - can't be used when comparing strings
print(a)
# [(1, 'coding'), (2, 'love'), (2, 'i')]
```